# RecyclerView : Get last item position in KOTLIN

Tags: android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am trying to find last item position in recycler view in Kotlin.But could not find same method or property in Kotlin like in java.

```
 Int lastVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();//JAVA
```

Answer (score 2):

If `mLayoutManager` contains `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` "in java" then you definitely can also call in Kotlin.

One thing I would suggest you is to check if `mLayoutManager` is of type `LinearLayoutManager` (or if you cast it), since `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` doesn't have method `findLastVisibleItemPosition()`